# Why can't I impl std::error::Error for a generic type that is Display+Debug but has a generic parameter that is not?

Tags: rust, traits

Consider the following custom error enum in *Rust*:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyError<T: FromStr>
    where <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug
{
    Variant1,
    Variant2,
    FromStrErr(<T as FromStr>::Err),
}
```

***This works!***

One can `impl Display` for it. It is already `Debug` because of the `derive` macro. One can even use it as expected:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn parse(s: &str) -> Result<u32, MyError<u32>> {
        s.parse::<u32>().map_err(MyError::FromStrErr)
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", parse("32"));  //→ Ok(32)
    println!("{:?}", parse("32a")); //→ Err(FromStrErr(ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }))
}
```

What one *cannot* do, however, is `impl std::error::Error` for it:

```rust
impl<T: FromStr> std::error::Error for MyError<T>
    where <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug
{ }
```

Even though `MyError<T>` *is* `Debug + Display`, this `impl` produces the error: **`T` doesn't implement `Debug`**. 
Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=61f2e7673143b94f142795a7f00f5148

Details in the error message include:

- `T` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug` 
  This is true but ultimately irrelevant because `T` is not in the `struct` at all.
- **note: required for `MyError<T>` to implement `Debug`** 
  More interesting but blatantly incorrect because `MyError<T>` already *did* implement `Debug` just fine!

Obviously, there are innumerable ways to work around this error but what I want to know is *why* this is happening: why does the addition of a trait on the type break it?

Perhaps it is the neigh-impossible-to-discover `impl`s of `From<…> for Box<dyn …>` or the fact that it is not (yet) in `core` but anything even vaguely related to `std::error::Error` always leaves me with an uneasy feeling that there is some "magic" behind the scenes that is specific to that trait, that I don't understand and that I'll probably discover in a round-about way six months from now when I've moved on from whatever is currently blocking me. Intriguingly, however, this is not the case in this case – making my own marker trait as an experiment produces exactly the same error:

```rust
pub trait MyErrorTrait: fmt::Debug + fmt::Display { }

impl<T: FromStr> MyErrorTrait for MyError<T>
    where <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug
{ }
```

This snippet *also* produces an error that declares that `T` is not `Debug` (acknowledged) and that `T` must be `Debug` for `MyError<T>` to implement `Debug` – that latter part being false. (Snippet included in *playground gist*, linked above, but commented out: ll.27-31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. It is true that `MyError` implements `Debug`, but *with the wrong bounds*.

`#[derive]` always creates simple bounds: for each generic parameter, it creates a `T: Trait` bound. In your case, the derived `Debug` implementation looks like:

```rust
impl<T: FromStr> fmt::Debug for MyError<T>
where
    <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug,
    T: fmt::Debug,
{ ... }
```

The `T: fmt::Debug` bound was generated by `#[derive]`, and the other copied verbatim from the struct's bounds. Can you spot the error? We require `T: Debug`, while we should only require `T::Err: Debug`! Since you try to implement `std::error::Error` for *any* `T` (as long as `T::Err: Debug`), and not just `T`s who are `Debug`, and `Error` has `Debug` as a supertrait, the compiler issues an error - `Debug` is not implemented *where `T: !Debug`*.

There is desire to create a so-called "perfect derive" - a derive that generates the correct bounds in cases like that. In the meantime, you need to implement the trait manually.

Comment: ~~Wow. Perfect answer in no time at all. Very helpful... er ... for understanding which is, I suppose, what I was angling after, anyway.~~
On the topic of "perfect derive": Could you provide an RFC №, issue № or other link for me to append to my ever-growing, jam-tomorrow list that I track?

Comment: (To be fair to Rust, a whole 80% of that jam-tomorrow list is basically tracking issues for stuff that is not yet `const` on stable.)

Comment: WAIT: no! I still don't understsand. Your answer seems to make sense but why doesn't it break *before* I `impl` the extra trait? Surely, if what you write is true, `derive(Debug)` would have failed without the trait `impl` in the first place?

Comment: @Xharlie There is no RFC currently, but there is [a blog post](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2022/04/12/implied-bounds-and-perfect-derive/) and a [lang team design proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/152).

Comment: @Xharlie It would... If you hadn't have the `where <T as FromStr>::Err: fmt::Debug` in the struct declaration. `#[derive]` also copy the bounds of the struct (I also said that in the answer) and thus you have _both_ `T: Debug` and `T::Err: Debug`. And you don't have to believe me, you can just inspect the macro-expanded code.

Comment: It feels like I can `derive(Debug)` and even format the type as `"{:?}"` but somehow that only fails when I implement a trait that has `Debug` as a super-trait, suggesting that super-traits are somehow *more* than just the existence of an `impl` of the trait?

Comment: @Xharlie Nope. It is just that you implemented the trait even for `T: !Debug` (because you didn't put a bound `T: Debug`) and thus you created a constraint for `MyError: Debug` even when `T: !Debug`, a constraint that didn't exist before.

Comment: Ah. I see. By coincidence, my example has `T` as `u32` which is also `Debug` and therefore the trait from the `derive` applies. So it just **looks** like the `derive(Debug)` is working as expected even though it is not.